# Find mean values in for-loop over distributed range

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, mean

I have a data like below:

```
49.6    46.1
49.65   46.3
50.1    47.03
50.2    47.06
51.35   46.027
51.36   46.20
```

I want to find the mean values of both column based on specific range of first column. for example in range of [49-50) I should calculate the mean values of the first column and  mean of corresponding values in the second column. In this example the sub-array (first column only) with numbers

```
49.6    
49.65
```

will be in range of [49-50) so I want to find the mean value for them and the mean value of the corresponding values in the 2nd column.

The range would be like `49:1:100`. The code below doesn't work properly.

```
for i=49:1:100
    meanWithinRange(i) = mean(data(i,1));
end
```

Comment: What do you mean "i want to find mean value for them and mean value of 2nd column's corresponding values"? Which range are you choosing for the second column?

Comment: @Goldname The same range as first column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for logical indexing.

First, create a logical array for the in-range values of column 1:

```
A=[49.6    46.1
   49.65   46.3
   50.1    47.03
   50.2    47.06
   51.35   46.027
   51.36   46.20];

I = A(:,1)>=49 & A(:,1)<50;
```

I is a logical column vector, and is `true` for the rows that are in range. You can use this to index the rows you want:

```
>> A(I,:)
ans =
   49.6000   46.1000
   49.6500   46.3000
```

So now you can simply compute the `mean` of this result:

```
>> mean(A(I,:))
ans =
   49.6250   46.2000
```